# Doesn't the meaning of the word "neither" make using the conjunction "nor" after it unnecessary?

Tags: word-choice, neither-nor

What does "neither" mean if you can't use "or" with it?

Comment: It's redundant, which is important when  bounding options, especially in speech. The double N of _neither ... nor_ reinforces the logic -- it's **not** _either ... or_.

Comment: @John Lawler Can you please explain how the redundancy is important for bounding options, or reinforces the logic? If we need "or", what meaning is "neither" meant to evince?

Comment: Negation. It's DeMorgan's Law - **Not (A Or B)** is equivalent to **(Not A) And (Not B)**. If you say a negative before an _or_, it's not clear what's being bounded, since parentheses aren't pronounced. So English has a double-barreled negative _Neither..Nor_ to separate the two chunks that are conjoined and make sure they're both understood as negative.

Comment: Wait... is this the same as your other strangely edited question? The one where you're copying all the comments into the question itself? If this is intended as a redo, you should delete the other question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Isn't “nor” superfluous when preceded by “neither”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/540788/isnt-nor-superfluous-when-preceded-by-neither)